# Is $(x^2-y^2-1)^2+4x^2y^2 <1$ an open set?

Tags: calculus, general-topology, complex-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I must answer, for some sets, if they are: i) open, ii)closed, iii)bounded, iv) compact

I've got the following set:

$$\{z\in \mathbb{C}; |z^2-1|<1\}$$

if I suppose $z=x+iy$ I get that this set if the set of reals $x,y$ that satisfy:

$$(x^2-y^2-1)^2+4x^2y^2 <1$$

Which is this, according to Wolfram Alpha:

[image]

Well, it looks like open, but what about that point in the middle? I also think it's not closed, so not compact. It's, however, bounded because I can fit it entirely inside an open ball

Comment: So, is $f(x,y) = (x^2-y^2-1)^2+4x^2y^2$ continuous or not? If it is, you can answer whether or not $\{(x,y):f(x,y)<1\}$ is open.

Comment: @JoeyZou yes, it's continuous, so the set should be open, but I cannot use that in my course

Comment: That middle point is not actually an element of the set. (The boundaries of the petals are also not included, if that helps visualization.) Plugging in $(0,0)$ for $(x,y)$ yields $1<1$, false.

Comment: Well you can't use graphing software to prove anything, and if you can't use very basic results about continuity, I'm not sure what we can do for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that $\{z\in\mathbb{C}: |z^2-1|<1\}$ is open, let $z\in\mathbb{C}$ satisfy $|z^2-1|<1$. We want to show that
$$\exists\delta>0: (|h|<\delta\implies |(z+h)^2-1|<1). $$
Note that
$$ ((z+h)^2-1)-(z^2-1) = 2zh+h^2 $$
so by the triangle inequality
$$ |(z+h)^2-1| \le |z^2-1| + |2zh+h^2|. $$
If we write $|z^2-1| = 1-\epsilon$, then $\epsilon>0$, and so it suffices to find $\delta>0$ such that
$$ |h|<\delta \implies |2zh+h^2| < \epsilon. $$
Now let $\delta>0$ satisfy
$$ y < \delta \implies 2|z|y+y^2 < \epsilon. $$
(It should be clear that such a $\delta$ exists. For example, try to show that $\delta = \min\left(1,\frac{\epsilon}{2|z|+1}\right)$ works.)

Then
$$ |h| < \delta\implies |2zh+h^2|\le 2|z||h|+|h|^2 < \epsilon $$
as desired.

Answer (score 1):

It is perhaps interesting to get the general result. Let $n$ be a natural, $a$ a real and $P$ a polynomial of $n$ variables. Then the set $$S_{a,P}=\{(x_1,...,x_n) : P(x_1,...,x_n)<a\}$$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the usual topology. To notice that, just remark that $$S_{a,P} = P^{-1}((-\infty,a))$$ and that $P$ is continuous since it is a polynomial. Of course you can can replace $P$ by any continuous function.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$f(x,y)=(x^2-y^2-1)^2+4x^2y^2$$
is continuous.  The set $\{x\in\mathbb{R}:x<1\}$ is open.  Now using the [technical definition of a continuous function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Continuous_functions_between_topological_spaces) (that the preimage of an open set is open), we see that 
$$f^{-1}((-\infty,1))=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:(x^2-y^2-1)^2+4x^2y^2<1\}$$
is an open set.